# please translate this text from My Mother-In-Law from China. I don't speak any Chinese

Tags: translation

I am having health problems and received a text from my mother-in-law from China, who I have never met.  I would really love to know what she said.  Can you please translate this text for me?  Thank you!!  =)

Use this link to see the photo I took of the text:
http://s1099.photobucket.com/user/tnlizzy316/media/Screen%20Shot%202017-02-08%20at%201.13.03%20PM.png.html?sort=3&o=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's“Cheer up, I'm praying for you and may God bless you. May everything goes well and all wishes come true.”

Answer (score 0):

The first word 加油 is hard to be directly translated to English. I here translate it as "Keep calm and hold on".

Translation:

Keep calm and hold on. I'm praying for you and may God bless you. May everything goes well and all wishes come true.

Comment: Well, a not so fancy way of interpreting 加油 is: everything will be fine.

Comment: some discussion on '加油' http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?3,115967,115973#msg-115973

Comment: Basically, 加油 is a supportive word,  urging someone to "keep pressing on and not relent."

Comment: 加油 is indeed very hard to translate because it has multiple meanings in different context. And I myself never use this phrase.

Answer (score 0):

"The first word 加油 is hard to be directly translated to English. I here translate it as "Keep calm and hold on"."

She's encouraging you to keep trying and not give up.  Literally "more oil" or "step on the gas".  Best wishes to you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you mother-in-law is taking a great effort to send a "inter-cultural" message.

> 加油! (Keep up the good works)
>
> 我天天为你祈祷， 愿上帝保佑你。(May God bless you)
>
> 一帆风顺（Bon voyage）心想事成(All the best)。

Just read the message with a smirk.